# Is it possible to install different versions of a library in one place?

Tags: c++, cmake

#### The Requirement

I want to have multi versions of a library installed in one place(e.g. the default system prefix path) using CMake to be used like: `find_package(Package 1.0.0 REQUIRED)`.

- Why just don't set some paths?

  - Because I'm an idiot at remembering paths and flags and other related stuff and I think it's the CMake's `find_package` job to handle it.

#### The Problem

The `find_package`'s version parameter is just an ordinary parameter [that will be passed to the package `*VersionConfig.cmake`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#config-mode-version-selection:%7E:text=CMake%20does%20not%20establish%20any%20convention%20for%20the%20meaning%20of%20version%20numbers.%20Package%20version%20numbers%20are%20checked%20by%20%22version%22%20files%20provided%20by%20the%20packages%20themselves%20or%20by%20FetchContent.) file for version checking and if that file doesn't exists [CMake will treat it as an error](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#config-mode-version-selection:%7E:text=assumed%20to%20not%20be%20compatible%20with%20any%20requested%20version). So we couldn't install different version in the same place.

#### Minimal CMake Configuration

```
file(WRITE Library.H "void Function();")
file(WRITE Library.C "void Function() {}")

add_library(Library SHARED Library.H Library.C)
target_include_directories(Library 
  PUBLIC 
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/Library>
)
set_target_properties(Library PROPERTIES VERSION 1.0.0)

install(TARGETS Library EXPORT LibraryConfig)
install(FILES Library.H DESTINATION include/Library)
install(EXPORT LibraryConfig DESTINATION lib/cmake/Library)

include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
write_basic_package_version_file(
  ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/LibraryConfigVersion.cmake
  VERSION 1.0.0
  COMPATIBILITY SameMajorVersion
)
install(
  FILES ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/LibraryConfigVersion.cmake 
  DESTINATION lib/cmake/Library
)
```

#### Possible Solution

I just apply version to the target name in form of `${PROJECT_NAME}-${PROJECT_VERSION}`:

1. I changed the export name:

```
install(TARGETS Library EXPORT Library-1.0.0Config)
install(
  EXPORT Library-1.0.0Config
  DESTINATION lib/cmake/Library-1.0.0Config
)
```

2. And the `INSTALL_INTERFACE` for the include directories:

```
target_include_directories(Library
  PUBLIC
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/Library-1.0.0>
)
```

3. And the `OUTPUT_NAME` property of the target:

```
set_target_properties(Library
  PROPERTIES
    OUTPUT_NAME Library-1.0.0
)
```

The result:

```
file(WRITE Library.H "void Function();")
file(WRITE Library.C "void Function() {}")

add_library(Library SHARED Library.H Library.C)
target_include_directories(Library 
  PUBLIC 
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/Library-1.0.0>
)
set_target_properties(Library PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME Library-1.0.0)

install(TARGETS Library EXPORT Library-1.0.0Config)
install(FILES Library.H DESTINATION include/Library-1.0.0)
install(EXPORT Library-1.0.0Config DESTINATION lib/cmake/Library-1.0.0)
```

But with this approach, I always have to specify the version: `find_package(Target-1.0.0 REQUIRED)`.

Comment: "The find_package's version parameter is just an ordinary parameter that will be passed to the package `*VersionConfig.cmake` file for version checking and if that file doesn't exists CMake will treat it as an error. So we couldn't install different version in the same place." - I don't get your implication about not being able to install different versions in the same place. No one enforce you to use `write_basic_package_version_file` for create `*VersionConfig.cmake` file. You may write that file by yourself and put into it the logic which you want.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, Could you could show me HOW TO DO THAT in a working example? As far as I could understand from the documents: CMake's `find_package` is looking for a file named `<lowercasePackageName>-config-version.cmake` or `<PackageName>ConfigVersion.cmake` so as I explained in the **Possible Solution** section: I just apply the version to the `<PackageName>` section which force me to mention the version on every `find_package`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the ready code for your requirements, and I have no time to write it. In my first comment I just noted that you don't need to treat semantic of `*VersionConfig.cmake` file as if it limits your semantic of "multiversion installation": You could write that file by yourself and put any logic into that file. Likewise, you could write by yourself the file `LibraryConfig.cmake`, and put into it the logic needed by you.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, Besides that I put the minimal code required for testing, I really really really know all that I could write those files by myself. The thing is okay I wrote that logic, how do I install it? I will install version-1 and it will put the version file in a path after that I install version-2 which also put the same file in the same path and cause overriding.  Rename to prevent overriding? then I must set some paths for CMake to find it. I think I just rewrite all my question chunk by chunk in the comments :)

Comment: Yes, when **install** your library files (`.so` or `.a`), you need to install different versions into **different locations** and/or with different names. Also you need to select different locations/names for EXPORT files (installed with `install(EXPORT)`). But you need to have only one copy of  `LibraryVersionConfig.cmake` and `LibraryConfig.cmake` files. The latter file should be able to select and include the proper EXPORT file, according to the requested version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working in Config Mode of `find_package`, so the search mode [according to the documents](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#version-selection:%7E:text=%3Cprefix%3E/(lib/%3Carch,CMake)/%20(W/U)) is like:

```bash
<prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib*|share)/cmake/<name>*/                 (U)
<prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib*|share)/<name>*/                       (U)
<prefix>/(lib/<arch>|lib*|share)/<name>*/(cmake|CMake)/         (U)
```

So you need to:

1. Change the `INSTALL_INTERFACE` to point to a directory tagged with the library version(with whatever policy you prefer for version matching).
2. Install your package's config files in a directory tagged with the library version(again with your preferred version matching policy).
3. Provide a version config file and installed it beside the config files. A version config file is required for version matching.
4. Change the `OUTPUT_NAME` property of the target to a name tagged with the version.

   - If you instead set `VERSION` or `SOVERSION` property, the result will be a non-version tagged symlink to the tagged one. It will be overridden by other versions and It could cause problems if anyone used it without using CMake.

So your sample with above modifications could be like:

```
file(WRITE Library.H "void Function();")
file(WRITE Library.C "void Function() {}")

add_library(Library SHARED Library.H Library.C)
target_include_directories(Library 
  PUBLIC 
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/Library-1.0.0>
)
set_target_properties(Library PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME 1.0.0)

install(TARGETS Library EXPORT LibraryConfig)
install(FILES Library.H DESTINATION include/Library-1.0.0)
install(EXPORT LibraryConfig DESTINATION lib/cmake/Library-1.0.0)

include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
write_basic_package_version_file(
  ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/LibraryConfigVersion.cmake
  VERSION 1.0.0
  COMPATIBILITY SameMajorVersion
)
install(
  FILES ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/LibraryConfigVersion.cmake 
  DESTINATION lib/cmake/Library-1.0.0
)
```

With this approach doesn't matter how many version of the library is installed using the same prefix path, the only important thing is the EXACT version name. And the usage could be requesting for a version `find_package(Target 1.0.0)` or the last available version `find_package(Target)`(based on the search policy and the version matching policy).